Nystrom Approximation
I'm going through the proof of the Nystrom approximation. But I have some trouble with it.
Assume that we have n points, and we choose the first m points. calling the first m points as $R$ and the rest n-m points as $S$. so we have:
$$
X = [x_1, x_2, \dots, x_m, x_{m+1}, \dots, x_n]=[R \quad S]
$$
Now, if we construct the kernel matrix, we will have the following block matrix:
$$
K = X^TX = \begin{pmatrix} R^TR & R^TS \\ S^TR & S^TS\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} A & B \\ B^T & C\end{pmatrix}
$$
The goal of the algorithm is to approximate the matrix by having the first $m$ points, so want to approximate $S^TS$ by having $R^TR$ and $R^TS$.
First, we perform the singular value decomposition on the $A$:
$$
A = R^TR = U\Sigma U^T \qquad \text{Note that $R^TR$ is symmetric}
$$
so we have:
$$
R = \Sigma^{1/2}U^T
$$
Now, we go to the $B$:
$$
B = R^TS = U\Sigma^{1/2}S \rightarrow S = \Sigma^{-1/2}U^TB
$$
Now that we have the $S$, we can compute the $C$ part of the matrix $K$:
$$
C = S^TS = (B^TU\Sigma^{-1/2})(\Sigma^{-1/2}U^TB) = B^T \underbrace{U\Sigma^{-1}U^T}_{A^{-1}}B = B^T A^{-1}B 
$$
So we can compute the matrix $C$ based on $A$ and $B$.
Where does the approximation in the Nystrom method occur? For example, if we assume that $n = 1000$ and $m = 20$, then $R = [x_1, \dots, x_m]$ would have dimensions $(d, 20)$, where $d$ is the dimensionality of the points. Meanwhile, the $R$ obtained from the SVD of $A$ has dimensions $(20, 20)$. Is this why we consider the approximation accurate if the matrix $K$ has rank less than or equal to $m$? I'm a little confused
